# Injecting content into a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div called 'middle' which contains a textarea element. I want to inject some text from another div from another page into this textarea. I do this with jquery, using:

```
$('#IDofTextarea').load('url' +  ' #divToBaInjected');
```

This works fine on IE, but not on Firefox. I think it is because, the injected content also contains html tags. If i inject into middle i get:

```
<div id="desc">Content of div.</div>
```

I have tried injecting the content into another div, and then loading it in the textare with getElementById('anotherdiv').innerHTML, but it injects the wrong(old) value od the div(only on firefox, i sorted the caching problem on the ie).

So, is there a way i could somehow strip those tags and load only the text into the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement the load function's callback, which is an optional parameter you have left out, or change from the $.load function to the $.ajax function and implement the callback there. I recommend implementing the functionality with the [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) because it makes the internals of the AJAX call more explicit and easier to understand. In this case, you will need to implement a function called "success" which will strip the response's surrounding HTML tags before changing the web page's DOM.